# PagerDuty Export All Historical Incidents

Tags: python, pagerduty

Does anyone have a way to export all historical incidents from PagerDuty? I can't seem to make it work by using any of the options in here:

https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/9d0b4b12e36f9-list-incidents

So I've been trying to do it in python using https://pagerduty.github.io/pdpyras/

My simple script looks like this:

```
import os
from pdpyras import APISession

api_key = os.environ['PD_API_KEY']
session = APISession(api_key, default_from="fake.email.com")

for incident in session.iter_all('incidents'):
    print(incident)
```

This only exports about the last month worth of incidents. I can't seem to find a parameter to pass into this which will allow me to export ALL incidents.

Comment: I created an API Access Key in the Integrations section & tried using this script however I get this error & not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am using the right key. ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export-pd-incidents.py", line 9, in <module>
    api_key = os.environ["xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Comment: This fixed my above problem, replacing all the line above `for incident in` :  

`from pdpyras import APISession`
`api_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'`
`session = APISession(api_token)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make multiple calls using the `since` and `until` parameters to request incidents for a specific time range.  The default time range is 1 month, and the maximum time range is 6 months.

The maximum number of incidents that it will return for a given time range is 10,000, if I remember correctly.  This means that you will need to submit requests for separate time ranges that end up covering the entire 6 months that are available such that each time span for which you submit a request does not result in more than 10k incidents.

I do not personally use `pdpyras`, but it appears that you should be able to pass `params={'since': '...', 'until': '...'}` to `iter_all` to achieve this.

If you use either a [date](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) or a [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object in your code for the `since`/`until` values, then you can use `.isoformat()` on those objects to produce a value that PagerDuty will accept.